# How to check if a function parameter is constant in dart?

Tags: dart

follow code, how to check params `list` is `const` ?

```
void doStuff({List<int> list = const [1, 2, 3]}) {
  list.add(10);
  print(list);
}

void main() {
  doStuff();// runtime error: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
  doStuff([1, 2, 3]); // OK
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to check if an object is constant. In fact, being constant is not a property of the object, but of the expression creating it. The object is just like any other object.
The difference is that when the constant object is created, it's canonicalized with other constant-created objects with the same state.

So, you can't.

It seems you are really looking at a list, and trying to tell if it can be modified. There are unmodifiable lists which are not constants, and if I really wanted to, I could create a "modifiable" constant-created list (storing the data outside of the object). Checking for being constant might not be what you really need.

However, there is also no way to check whether a list is modifiable, short of trying to modify it, and catching the error.

What you should do is to *document* that the function requires a modifiable list, and then just let it throw if someone passes a non-modifiable list.

Comment: Additionally, if the function needs a default value like in the example, just make the parameter nullable and do `list ??= [1, 2, 3];` in the function body.